# Changing input values after row has been removed

Tags: javascript, input, tags, html-parsing

I'm trying to create a tool where the user clicks on a button and it adds a label,input and remove button.  I have it all working for the most part but there is only couple things missing.  If the user had let's say adds "4" items and he/she deleted item "2"; I want the label value to subtract
"-1" of its value and the id of that item to subtract "-1" of its value.  Any help would be appreciated!

I have created a jsFiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/fUhL8/

HTML

```
    <input type="input" value="0" id="theValue" />
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    function addItem() {

    if ($('#theValue').val() < 10){

    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;

    var newdiv = document.createElement('form');
    var newlabel = document.createElement('input');
    var newinput = document.createElement('input');
    var newbutton = document.createElement('input');
    var divIdName = 'Address'+num;
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newbutton.setAttribute('type','button');
    newbutton.setAttribute('onclick','onclick=confirmDelete("'+divIdName+'"); return false;');
    newbutton.setAttribute('value','Delete');
    //newlabel.innerHTML ='Address('+num+')';
    newlabel.setAttribute('value','Address '+num+':')
    newlabel.setAttribute('size','8');
    newlabel.setAttribute('class','label');
    newlabel.setAttribute('readonly','true');
    newinput.setAttribute('type','text');
    newinput.setAttribute('id',divIdName+'_input');
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.appendChild(newlabel);
    newdiv.appendChild(newinput);
    newdiv.appendChild(newbutton);
    }

    else{
return false;
    };

    }

    function confirmDelete(divNum){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " +divNum+"?")) 
{

var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
var getLabel = olddiv.getElementsByClassName("label");



var counter= $('#theValue').val();

$('#theValue').val( (counter-1<0)?counter:--counter );

//$(getLabel).nextAll().css( "color", "red" );

$(olddiv).nextAll().css('background-color', 'red').css('color','red');
d.removeChild(olddiv);

}
else{};
    }
```

Comment: Why do you assign each input an own id and put it in an own form anyway? I don't see the necessity of doing that.

Comment: I technically don't have to have an ID on the input.  But that is not the issue.  I need to figure out how to change the value "-1" on the inputs selected after the one that was deleted.

Comment: If you don't need all the forms and ID's I recommend you don't use them and instead just put the `input`s in one form. You can then treat your inputs as a collection rather than indivduals: Every time an input is deleted, do the following afterwards: Select all inputs in your form (e.g. with `getElementsByTagName()`); Starting with the index of the lastly deleted row, update the label (just use your loop counter for that!) for each input up to the last one